# User bypasses DenyUsers on Debian 8

Tags: ssh, users

So I have a user called `spring` and although my `sshd_config` says `DenyUsers spring`, I can login with PuTTY into that user. I restarted the SSH service of course.

The non-comment lines from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Port xxxxx
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
Match User myotheruser
        PasswordAuthentication no
DenyUsers spring
```

What do I have to check?

Comment: Hello Gerolmed. Please include all non-comment lines from your `sshd_config` file. Use `grep '^[^#]' /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and [add it to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/494630/edit), remembering to select the block and use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: besides the configuration, are you able to show any logs?

Comment: @roaima added the config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put, `DenyUsers` before the first or only `Match User`. Or use the `AllowUsers` directive before the first `Match User` to only allow the users you want.

Or use both directives like:

```
AllowUsers somealloweduser
DenyUsers *
```

The Allow and Deny directives are executed like firewall tables, order matters. The above will allow somealloweduser and deny all others. If the Deny was first no one would be able to connect.

Comment: I could swear the last rule wins in sshd_config, but I might be wrong.

Comment: All I know is that is what worked in my case. So that is what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the DenyUsers directive is being treated as part of the Match clause, rather than an unconditional restriction. So I'd try moving it above the Match entry, and see if that helps.